# Android Notification METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART overlapping

Tags: android, kotlin

I've noticed since my pixel updated to Android 13, updating foreground service bitmaps overlap.

Example:

#1
[image: notification 1]

#2
[image: Update to notification]

As you can see, instead of clearing, it layers on top. My notification code is as follows:

```kotlin
private fun refreshNotification() {
        val sounds = // code
        if (sounds.isEmpty()) {
            if (!audioFocusTakenBackground) {
                stopForegroundService()
            }
            return
        } else {
            val item = // code
            val icon = // code
            if (icon != null && icon.isNotEmpty()) {
                val loader = this@SoundPlayerService.imageLoader
                val req = ImageRequest.Builder(this@SoundPlayerService)
                    .data(icon)
                    .target { result ->
                        val bitmap = (result as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
                        buildNotification(bitmap, item)
                    }
                    .build()
                loader.enqueue(req)
            } else {
                buildNotification(null, item)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun buildNotification(imageBitmap: Bitmap?, item: MediaItem){
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID).apply {
            val name: String = // code

            // update session metadata
            mediaSession.isActive = true
            if (imageBitmap != null) {
                mediaSession.setMetadata(
                    MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                        .putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, imageBitmap)
                        .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, name)
                        .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "Artist")
                        .build()
                )
            } else {
                mediaSession.setMetadata(
                    MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                        .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, name)
                        .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "Artist")
                        .build()
                )
            }

            setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            setContentTitle(getString(R.string.action_now_playing))
            setContentText(name)
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon_small)
            setContentIntent(relaunchPendingIntent())
            setSilent(true)
            setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            setAutoCancel(false)
            color = this@SoundPlayerService.getColor(R.color.magenta)

            addAction(NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_playbar_stop, getString(R.string.action_stop), stopIntent))

            setStyle(
                androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0)
                    .setMediaSession(mediaSession.sessionToken)
                    .setShowCancelButton(true)
                    .setCancelButtonIntent(stopIntent)
            )
        }
        if (isForegroundActive){
            updateNotification(builder)
        } else {
            startForegroundApp(builder)
        }
    }

    private fun updateNotification(builder: NotificationCompat.Builder){
        Timber.i("UPDATE FOREGROUND SERVICE")
        val notificationManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }

    private fun startForegroundApp(builder: NotificationCompat.Builder){
        if (!audioFocusTakenBackground && Application.instance.isAppInForeground && !isForegroundActive) {
            isForegroundActive = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                startForeground(
                    ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                    builder.build(),
                    ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK
                )
                true
            } else {
                startForeground(
                    ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                    builder.build()
                )
                true
            }
        }
    }

    private fun stopForegroundService(){
        isForegroundActive = false
        stopForeground(true)
    }
```

#1 `refreshNotification` is called, it tries to download an image if available

#2 `buildNotification` is called from `refreshNotification`

#3  Depending on whether the foreground service has been started already or not, it is either started, or the notification updated.

Just curious if anyone else has encountered this and if there is a workaround.

Thanks!

EDIT:

also tried setting `setLargeIcon(bitmap)` as well, to no avail